# Create objects with different colors (hues) from a selected object (group of many simple colored objects)

Tags: inkscape

I'm working with Kenny's game assets and am trying to get more color options with a particular block object from his inkscape file:

[image: Kenney Game Assets (version 40)> Art > Toy brick pack (100 assets)> Vector]

These, along with four more blocks, are already available in the file but I need to add more colors like pink, red, and violet. Now, these are three objects but with at lease three different shade of the same color. Is there an easy way to change the color so that the shades are taken care of automatically i.e. work on the block object only and not handle the three objects separately?

I have Photoshop available apart from Inkscape.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Currently reading the forum thread: http://www.inkscapeforum.com/viewtopic.php?t=339

Comment: Filter > Color > Color Shift. Too slow and Inkscape closes suddenly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is indeed "Filter > Color > Color Shift", but I think in your case, you should have an object, used as a base color, then some semi-transparent shades of gray above it.

So you'd only have to change the base object's color.

Comment: But it is also the only thing that's working